# Split lines with lines

Tags: qgis, line

I would like to split a line with a smaller line on QGIS in order to have the rest. I used split line with line but it doesn't work.

Sorry I have difficultes to explain because I'm not an English speaker. I have a big line and a smaller line which are on the space. I would to have the subtraction of them. I would like to split lines in a layer with lines in another layer using processing tools. When I try I only have the full segment as a result and not the subtraction of both

This is the bigger line :
[image]

This is the smaller line :
[image]

I would like the subtraction (the red circle) of them  (in yellow it's still the bigger line and in green it's still the smaller line)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" database compilation effort operates. "It doesn't work" is not a description that is going to generate useful responses. You need to describe **exactly** what inputs you used and the **exact** result, and how that didn't meet your expectations.

Comment: Do you mean "split one line with just one line manually" or "split lines in a layer with lines in another layer using Processing tools"? If you do not ask in more detail, It's possible not to get useful answer or users will have to ask questions like that.

Comment: Sorry i have difficultes to explain because I'm not an english speaker. I have a big line and a smaller line which are on the space. I would to have the soustraction of them. I would like to split lines in a layer with lines in another layer using processing tools. When I try I only have the full segment as a result and not the soustraction of both.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, can you use a clip tool to capture the segments that are not overlaid. this will output a new feature class/shape file displaying all line segments that previsouly did not overlay. use the big line feature as input feature and the smaller lines as the clip feature

Comment: That's exactly what I want. However which clip tool should I use ? Because I tried the tool "clip line with line" several times and I had different results each time : It keeps the smaller line or the big line but I don't have the segment which is not overlaid.

Comment: Have you looked into [Symmetrical Difference](http://grindgis.com/software/qgis/basic-editing-tools-in-qgis)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your help. I tried symmetrical Difference and it gave me the line and also the contour of the buffer... I didn't try difference tool, i will try it.

Answer (score 2):

If we have the Longer line and the Shorter line on separate layers like below,

[image]

(1) Create a buffer around the Shorter line, by **Buffer** tool (QGIS 3.0 - `Processing Toolbox | Vector geometry | Buffer` / QGIS 2.18 - `Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector geometry tools | Fixed distance buffer`)

[image]

(2) Cut the Longer line by the buffer. We can use **Difference** tool (QGIS 3.0 - `Processing Toolbox | Vector overlay | Difference` / QGIS 2.18 - `Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector overlay tools | Difference`)

[image]

If the Longer and the Shorter lines are on the same layer, you will need to select the Shorter line and use `Selected features only` option. After that, the Step(2) is the same as the above.

Comment: These are the results :

The tool split line with line work but doest't give the same result all the time...

The buffer idea with the difference tool work even if it's a problem when you have perpendicular line with the buffer. 

The buffer with the symmetrical difference work but it let the contour of the buffer.